# What is the best way to externalize properties in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have a few mvn projects with almost the same properties. What is the best way to externalize these properties so i dont have them duplicated.

First the properties:

```
<properties>
    <!-- LOMBOK version -->
    <lombok.version>1.16.4</lombok.version>
    <!-- LOGGING versions -->
    <slf4j.version>1.6.4</slf4j.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.16</log4j.version>
    <!-- MAVEN COMPILER PLUGIN version -->
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.3</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.source.version>1.7</maven-compiler-plugin.source.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.target.version>1.7</maven-compiler-plugin.target.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.compilerVersion>1.7</maven-compiler-plugin.compilerVersion>
</properties>
```

Then dependenciesManagement:

```
<dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- LOMBOK DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- LOGGING DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- LOGGING DEPENDENCIES - LOG4J -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>           

</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: What kind of properties? Can you show some examples?

Comment: I bet that something like <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>

Comment: Yes me too, but this is the wrong to do. For such purposes a dependencyManagement exist...and properties are the wrong way for this.

Comment: @khmarbaise yes i know but i dont want for every project to define a dependencyManagement or the pluginManagement section.

Comment: Why for every project? The pluginManagement section should be fined only once in a corporate pom. The dependencyManagement section could be defined either in BOM (and use it via import scope)...BTW: You should use `maven.compiler.target`and `maven.compiler.source` instead of the given values, cause these are default properties. See the doc of [maven-compiler-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html)

Comment: @khmarbaise I too have same use case where I want to externalize the versions so that I can update on every intervals as I have distributed arch and having more than 100 + repos incase if I  have to update the common repo versions to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a parent project which is used by all your sub-projects. Move the common properties into a parent maven project, and then add something like this to your sub-projects:

```xml
<parent>
  <groupId>com.parent</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent-project</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <relativePath/>
</parent>
```